# Mathjax page size increase after rendering formulas

Tags: html, mathjax

I am trying to implement MathJax in mobile Application, I want to calculate the height of webpage, but after rendering formulas page size increases, Is there any possibility to prevent increase in HTML page size of after rendering formula? Or to keep formulas within same space??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the typeset expressions have different heights from the text of the TeX form (if that is what you are using), the height of the page will change when the unformatted math is replaced by the typeset math.  There is really very little that you can do about that, other than enclosing the displayed math expressions in containers that have (minimum) heights set to roughly that of the typeset expressions.  But that would require your knowing what those heights will be before hand.

Alternatively, you could wait to calculate the height of the page until after the math was been processed (using `MathJax.Hub.Queue()` to queue the function that computed the height so that it runs after the initial typesetting is complete).